# Elements not showing up

Tags: html, css

There's a `<p>` that's not showing up, I also tried with a `<div>` but it doesn't change anything.
So why it does not  show?

```css
#loader-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#loader {
    -webkit-animation: rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #00c4ff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1001;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateplane {
    0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) }
    50% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) }
    100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)  rotateX(180deg) }
}

@keyframes rotateplane {
    0% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) 
  } 50% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg) 
  } 100% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
  }
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Sb2b3fQ.jpg);
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
    left: 0;
}
 
#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
    right: 0;
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);  /* IE 9 */
    transform: translateX(-100%);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
 
.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: translateX(100%);  /* IE 9 */
    transform: translateX(100%);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

.loaded #loader {
    opacity: 0;
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.loaded #loader {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
            transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right,
.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000); 
               transition: all 0.3s 0.3s ease-out;
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
                transform: translateY(-100%);
 
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 1s ease-out; 
                transition: all 0.3s 1s ease-out;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #3C4B57 0%, #1C262B 100%);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: patate;
    src: url(../fonts/patate.woff);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: reis;
    src: url(../fonts/reis.otf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: bizon;
    src: url(../fonts/bizon.otf);
}

.white {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(http://p1.pichost.me/640/69/1942134.png);
    background-size: cover;
}

.1ce {
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script>
            var startTime = Date.now();
            window.addEventListener("load", function(){
                var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].setAttribute("class", "loaded");
                }, Math.max(0, 10000 - (Date.now() - startTime)));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="loader-wrapper">
            <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
            <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
            <div id="loadingbar-frame"></div>
            <div id="loader"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="white"></div>
            <p class="1ce">BlaBlaBla</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rename your class from `.1ce` to a valid name (not starting with a number), like `.ice`, see if that works

Comment: Great, I made it an answer

Answer (score 0):

Rename your class from `.1ce` to a valid name (not starting with a number), like `.ice`